# Android: 'This item is not available in your country error' in beta testing

Tags: android, developer-console

I released my app for beta testing today and added a list of users including myself as testers. Now after publishing the app when I tried to download it myself I see following message:

`This item is not available in your country.`

I have added only my country, in my case India, in the list of countries in the Pricing and Distributing option on the developer console. I tried it with two phones, both with 3G and WiFi but no success. Can someone help me ? What am I missing?

**Update:** I just tried this with another tester and it works for her. We both are in the same country and I made her do it from my phone. The only difference is that I have a credit card added in my account, in her case it is not so. Does it have something do with it?

Answer (score 1):

The location your credit card is attributed to determines the location of your google play account.

Comment: I will try that, if it works I will accept your answer !!